# Can I change a return type to be a strict subtype and retain binary compatibility?

Tags: java, binary-compatibility

If I have some class:

```
import java.util.Date;
public final class Foo {
    private Date date;
    public Date getDate(){ return date; }
}
```

If I have compiled this as a binary and other people have built code against it, can I subsequently do this without breaking binary compatibility?

```
import java.sql.Date;
public final class Foo {
    private Date date;
    public Date getDate(){ return date; }
}
```

Note that `java.sql.Date` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`.

It seems obvious to me that, had I not declared the class final, then I would have broken source compatibility (i.e. someone could previously have compiled against my library a subclass of `Foo` which overrides the `getDate` method to return a `java.util.Date`; that code would no longer *compile* against my latest version). But does breaking source compatibility imply that binary compatibility is broken too? (that doesn't hold in other languages, such as scala)

Comment: You can run this [compatibility checker tool](https://lvc.github.io/japi-compliance-checker/) to see if you do or not.

Comment: What kind of binary compatibility you look for? what is compiled, and what is replaced? and how you load it?

Answer (score 4):

I tested this.

Unfortunately there is a `NoSuchMethodError` exception at the point of the call when a method's return type is changed to a subtype of the original type.

Making this change is thus not binary backwards compatible.

This is too bad...

### Test setup

```
test
├── c
├── c_int
│   └── C.java
├── c_num
│   └── C.java
└── Test.java
```

`test/c_num/C.java`:

```
package test.c;

public class C {
    public Number f() {
        System.out.println("f Number");
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

`test/c_int/C.java`:

```
package test.c;

public class C {
    public Integer f() {
        System.out.println("f Integer");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

`test/Test.java`:

```
package test;

import test.c.C;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        C b = new C();
        Number n = b.f();
        System.out.println(n);
    }
}
```

### Test

Compile the two `C` classes with different return type:

```
$ javac test/c_int/C.java
$ javac test/c_num/C.java
```

Compile `Test` against `C` with return type `Number`:

```
$ cp test/c_num/C.class test/c/
$ javac test/Test.java
```

Run `Test` against `C` with return type `Number`:

```
$ java test.Test
f Number
0.0
```

Run `Test` against `C` with return type `Integer`, without recompiling `Test`:

```
$ cp test/c_int/C.class test/c/
$ java test.Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.Number test.c.C.f()'
    at test.Test.main(Test.java:8)
```

### Bytecode

We can also see in the byte code that the method call to `f` contains the return type of the method:

```
$ javap -c test/Test.class
Compiled from "Test.java"
public class test.Test {
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       ...
       9: invokevirtual #4                  // Method test/c/C.f:()Ljava/lang/Number;
       ...
}
```

### Eclipse document

The Eclipse foundation maintain a document called [Evolving Java-based APIs](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Evolving_Java-based_APIs_2#Evolving_API_classes_-_API_methods_and_constructors).

The document states this about binary compatibility:

```
Evolving API classes - API methods and constructors
....
Change result type (including void)     -   Breaks compatibility
```

This does not make an exception about changes that only narrow the return type. All changes to the return type breaks binary compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way is to just test it yourself. Here is some snippet from official [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.12):

> **13.4.15. Method Result Type**
>
> Changing the result type of a method, or replacing a result type with
>   void, or replacing void with a result type, has the combined effect of
>   deleting the old method and adding a new method with the new result
>   type or newly void result (see §13.4.12).

and

> **13.4.12. Method and Constructor Declarations**
>
> Deleting a method or constructor from a class may break compatibility
>   with any pre-existing binary that referenced this method or
>   constructor; a NoSuchMethodError may be thrown when such a reference
>   from a pre-existing binary is linked. Such an error will occur only if
>   no method with a matching signature and return type is declared in a
>   superclass.

The way I read this is that if you are changing return type, no matter if it is a subtype of old type, means that you are deleting the old method and adding a new method and according to **13.4.12** it can break compatibility
with any pre-existing binary that referenced this method or constructor.